# Integration services project Templates missing in VS 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis-2012, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

I am trying to create Integration services project in VS 2015. i Installed the SQL Server Data Tools for VS 2015. i also installed SQL Server 2016.

I still dont see the templates.

can anyone please help.

Comment: By "integration services" do you mean for maps and schemas for biztalk?

Comment: have you checked integration services option in sql server installation?

Answer (score 2):

The current release of SQL Server Data tools for VS 2015 doesn't include the BI templates that you need for integration services etc, what you need to install is Microsoft's pre-release SSDT RC0 version, which now finally includes the SQL server database projects and the BI templates, finally it will all be in one place:

[Download SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Make sure you download the release from the link "Download the Latest SSDT Preview for Visual Studio 2015"

Comment: This was the first thing i installed and i still dont see the templates. Any idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking under the "Business Intelligence" section and not SQL Server?

Comment: I dont see the Business Intellegence section at all. Thats what is surprising to me.

Comment: Same problem here, installed this, no business intelligence section, but in vs 2017...

Comment: Same problem here in VS 2017.